# Different Python versions on my Mac related to missing module 'requests'?

Tags: python, python-requests, anaconda, homebrew

On my MacBook Pro (M1 Pro), I have installed Python 3.10 (and Idle) from Python.org. Apparently at some point I had also installed Python 3.8 (possibly using Anaconda).

In Terminal, Python 3.8 is the default version. In Idle, of course, it's 3.10.

I don't so much care about having two different versions of Python on my Mac. (Presumably v. 2 is here somewhere as well). But as I am playing around with NOAA tide api that wants to import requests, I run into a problem. In Idle, I get this error:

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Likewise, if I enter import requests in Terminal, I get an error:

```
 bash: import: command not found
```

I'm learning Python on my own and this problem has pretty much stymied my progress. I'd like to continue to use Idle but I would also like to be able to import requests. Is having two versions of Python on my Mac causing a problem?

Comment: The `bash: import: command not found` error has nothing to do with Python, as you aren't even *using* Python at that point.

Comment: How did you install `requests`? Typically, module installations put the new module in a directory specific to a particular version of Python.

Comment: Small detail, but Apple has not manufactured any device bearing the *PowerBook* branding since its supersession by the MacBook line in 2006. For the sake of accuracy, you should make sure you've accurately represented not only your hardware but all other specs you've provided here.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. (Thanks, Chepner). So 'import requests' does apparently work in Python 3.8 (in Terminal). I installed requests using PIP install.

So I would amend my original query to ask how do I get 'requests' to work in Idle? And is there some reason why Idle and Terminal can't use the same version of Python?

Comment: I successfully installed 'requests' library. To get the system path, I entered this into Python shell in Idle:
     import sys; sys.executable

Then using that file path, I did a Pip install in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, typing `import requests` into terminal directly does NOT execute a python command. Instead, it lets `bash` to execute that. However, `bash` does not know what `import` is. The correct method is:

1. Typing `python` in your terminal.
2. After the prompt `>>>`  pops up, type `import requests`